# Control anylogic through external programs

Tags: interface, anylogic, data-exchange

I want to use python or JAVA to control the anylogic model. For example, start or shutdown model, input and output data and so on.
Does Anylogic provide such an interface, like COM, Socket. or do i have to develop my own java interface to achieve the above functions.

Do you have any solution or advice?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for python, you can use this:

https://github.com/t-wolfeadam/AnyLogic-Pypeline
if a functionality is not there, you have to do it on your own.

But this is used to use python inside AnyLogic, if you want to use Python to run the model and such, I think you have to build your own thing

Comment: Thank you very much for your response

I am currently doing research on data-exchange interfaces. pypline is good idea for later work to optimize the production system. thanks for your advice.